# In php how to remove the query string from URL and also filename the access the page?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a URL `https://testing.in/show_tmp?tmp=abcval`. I want a clean URL like `https://testing.in/abcval` without breaking the functionality of the site. My website is built in Core PHP. I know we can achieve this using the htacess file but i don't know how to do it please help me out.

htaccess file code

```
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW SSL_REDIRECT:connectwithme.in
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^connectwithme.in$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE SSL_REDIRECT:connectwithme.in
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?show_tmp$ [NC]
RewriteRule /?(.+) show_tmp?tmp=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: When someone types in `https://testing.in/abcval`, then you want `https://testing.in/show_tmp?tmp=abcval` execution to be shown internally ?

Comment: What happens if someone directly visits `https://testing.in/show_tmp?tmp=abcval`?

Comment: @vivek_23 if some directly opens the page `https://testing.in/show_tmp?tmp=abcval` it show the correct page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We add a rewrite condition as to current request URI should not contain `show_tmp` to avoid too may redirects issue. Later, we just capture the request URI and redirect to `show_tmp`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?show_tmp$ [NC]
RewriteRule /?(.+) show_tmp?tmp=$1 [NC,L,QSA,P]
```

**Demo:** https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=0ddbbf44-57e1-5c9b-9e83-500961e8050d

After assisting with Anydesk access, your final .htaccess should look like below:

```
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW SSL_REDIRECT:connectwithme.in
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^connectwithme.in$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE SSL_REDIRECT:connectwithme.in

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?assets/.+$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f #add this for any kind of file extension. If you want to display .html, then you will have to add .html also  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?assets/.+$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?show_tmp$ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/show_tmp?tmp=$1 [NC,L,QSA,P]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: @NitinJohnson For now, can you just remove all other rules and just test with this? Also, test on incognito mode.

Comment: tried as you said but still facing the same issue it shows 404 page

Comment: @NitinJohnson What's the URL when it gives you a 404?

Comment: @NitinJohnson Ok, can you show your complete .htaccess file when you added my script as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210654/discussion-between-nitin-johnson-and-vivek-23).